# Pipeline ‘does not define any stages’, but it does?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins and have decided to learn about the Pipeline declarative script. After reading and watching several tutorials on writing a simple Pipeline script, I decided to give it a go on Jenkins.

When running the simple script, it displays the following error message - ‘This Pipeline has run successfully, but does not define any stages. Please use the stage step to define some stages in this Pipeline’.

[image: Groovy Script]

[image: Console Output]

[image: Stage View or lack of]

However, after combing through the script and comparing it to the tutorial scripts online, everything appears to be precisely the same. So what is going on here? Is it perhaps a JRE/JDK issue since the Stage View is not displaying?

Any assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the declarative pipeline syntax plugin installed?

Comment: In the future please add the code to the question, not a screenshot of the code.  I can tell you for sure that your script is fine.  Have you tried assigning the pipeline to master node instead of any?  That would be my first troubleshooting step.  I have a suspicion you're doing something wrong that isn't being shown here ( like maybe youre looking at the wrong log ).  Please give us the Jenkins version

Comment: @MattSchuchard -- Many thanks for your suggestion! It worked!

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli -- Many thanks for the feedback! Very new to Stack Overflow as you can see -- I'll be sure to post the source code in the appropriate code format. The answer was that the declarative pipeline syntax plugin was not installed -- what an oversight! Thanks once again for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

In my case [Pipeline: Declarative](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition/) plugin was missing. You can also install

[Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator) plugin which includes this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this :

```
    pipeline {
        agent {label '**REPLACE THE agent name here**'}
           stages {
               stage('Hello'){
                     steps {
                           echo "Hello World"

                    }    

              } 
        
        }
}
```